# How to process each page of a multi-page PDF in place with imagemagick?

Tags: pdf, image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, image-editing

I have a multi-page PDF with photographed book pages. I want to remove gradients from every page to prepare for optical character recognition.

This command works fine on a PNG of a single page:

```
convert page.png \( +clone -blur 0x64 \) -compose minus -composite -channel RGB -negate page_deblurred.png
```

However, as soon as I try this on a multi-page PDF by using this command...

```
convert full.pdf \( +clone -blur 0x64 \) -compose minus -composite -channel RGB -negate full_deblurred.pdf
```

...I get a single-page PDF with inversed colors overlaid with text from several pages.

How do I tell imagemagick to process every page like it does with the PNG and return a multi-page PDF to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want in ImageMagick in one command line. You have to use -layers composite and separate your pdf and your blur processing by null:. This is the same process as merging animated gifs.

```
convert -density 288 image.pdf -write mpr:img null: \( mpr:img -blur 0x64 \) -compose minus -layers composite -channel RGB -negate -resize 25% image_deblurred.pdf
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works, but the output quality is too low for OCR. I took the liberty to submit a an edit adding the flag `-density 288` after `convert`. This massively increases the computation time, but the results are much better. One can use this flag to control the runtime-to-quality ratio.

Comment: I have further edited the answer so that the output size is not changed by the -density 288. Adding -resize 25% compensates for the -density 288 size increase. It will still take as long to process as without the -resize.

Answer (score 2):

As imagemagick does not seem to be capable to do this in one shot, I put together a script based on the suggestion Mark Setchell made in a comment to his answer.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

set -e

tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)

echo "Splitting PDF into single pages"
convert -density 288 "$1" "${tmpdir}/page-%03d.png"
for f in "$tmpdir"/page-*.png
do
    echo "Processing ${f##*/}"
    convert "$f" \( +clone -blur 0x64 \) -compose minus -composite -channel RGB -negate "$(printf "%s%s" "$f" "_gradient_removed.png")"
done
pdf_file_name_without_suffix="${1%.pdf}"
echo "Reassembling PDF"
convert "$tmpdir"/*_gradient_removed.png -quality 100 "$pdf_file_name_without_suffix"_gradient_removed.pdf

rm -rf "${tmpdir}"
```

It works fine with my material. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

It seems unlikely you'd want to pass a PDF to OCR, since Tesseract et al prefer PNG or NetPBM PPM files, so you might as well split your big PDF into individual PNG (or other) files:

```
convert full.pdf page-%03d.png
```

You can now remove gradients on individual pages, one at a time, and pass to OCR. Or you can use **GNU Parallel** to do them in parallel - please say if this in an option and I will write it up for you, if so.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Actually I'd prefer to use pdfsandwich which indeed takes PDFs as input and has some options built-in that I'd like to use.

Comment: Ok, I've not heard of pdfsandwich, but I guess I would still split the PDF into separate pages as above, remove the gradient from pages individually either in a `for` loop or in parallel, then recombine into a multi-page PDF for your preferred tool. Let me know if you like that approach and want a hand with any aspects.

Comment: If Imagemagick can't do the job on its own I'd happily accept every answer that produces the output that I want. I have trouble seeing the benefits of GNU Parallel in this case though since Imagemagick already uses all of my CPU cores when processing just a single file.